# parcel bundler - Unknown plugin "add-module-exports"

Tags: parceljs

I'm trying to use 'react-responsive' but I am getting the error message - Unknown plugin "add-module-exports

It looks like this relates to the fact that node_modules needs to be excluded but due to a bug in babel v6 (fixed in v7) adding `"ignore": "node_modules"` to the `.babelrc` file doesn't work.
https://github.com/contra/react-responsive/issues/131

It seems like parcel-bundler uses babel v6 so my question is , how can I ignore node_modules and get parcel to bundle without throwing an error?

Comment: There is an issue (not fixed) on ParcelJS gihub repo with similar problem: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/13
And even PR with fix but still in `WIP` state : https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/559
:(

Comment: Can you post the error log with the `add-module-exports` error?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue recently with parcel, installing `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` seemed to fix the issue